# If "Option Strict" is off, why does compilation fail with "Option Strict On"?

Tags: vb.net

I have inherited a VB.NET application that I need to compile so I can run dokumentation on it. I first received "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversion from x to y" errors, so I turned off the Option Strict option in the Project file.

So why do I still fail with the same error message?

Comment: Can you post the line that's causing the error?

Comment: Dim ExceptionHandler As ExceptionHandler = Me.LoadControl(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("PagesFolder") & "ExceptionHandler.ascx")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I first received "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversion from x to y" errors, so I turned off the Option Strict option in the Project file.

As opposed to, say, fixing the error? Pardon my sarcasm but you have chosen the wrong fix: instead of disabling `Option Strict` you **should** fix the error that the compiler indicated. After all, the whole point of `Option Strict` is to help make the code more robust.

That said, there are *four* places which control `Option Strict` (and all other options):

1. The Visual Studio options which control project defaults,
2. The project settings,
3. The `web.config` compiler command line,
4. On file basis, the top lines of a source code file.

Check that `Option Strict` is off in places 2., 3. and 4. and that it is on in place 1 (because turning `Option Strict Off` in general is a really, really bad idea). The problem should be gone then.

Also try disabling the setting *explicitly* in the `web.config`. I’m going on a limb here but according to [forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/p/935358/1106710.aspx) this can be done by adding the following directly inside the `<configuration>` node:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler compilerOptions ="/optionstrict-" language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript"
                  extension=".vb"
                  type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

… probably there already exists a `<compiler>` node – modify that.

Comment: is right. Please, please, pretty please, fix the problem by explicitly adding a proper cast operation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. First concern, fixing the error, no I'm not worried about that. Just want to get it into a buildable state so I can run the documenter on it. Second concern, Project file Option Strict is off, file level Option Stricts are off, and (good call!) the Web.Config has no reference to Option Strict.

Comment: @magma - Thanks for the concern, this is a legacy application that is already in production that I will be re-writing. Whatever options are compiled in there are already there and running, I just want to document it in its current state.

Comment: @grefly Hmm. Nevertheless, try disabling it manually; see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Option Strict is prevents program from automatic variable conversions, that is implicit data type conversions.